# Length of wire needed to graph a function

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Question:

> $$S = {(x,y): \left|||x|-2|-1\right| + \left|||y|-2|-1\right| = 1}$$
>   If S is made out of wire, find the length of the wire required.

I have no clue as to where to begin this question. Please note that this was a question on an exam and we weren't allowed any graphing equipment or calculator.

Comment: Your expression for S has an odd number of $|$ signs, so it is missing a closing $|$ somewhere.

Comment: Probably after the first -1

Answer (score 5):

To draw the graph, start with the graph of $$|x|+|y|=1$$ which is a square with corners at $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)$

The total length of wire is $4\sqrt{2}$.

Then consider the transformation to $$||x|-1|+||y|-1|=1$$ which has the effect of translating the square so it has its centre at $(1,1)$ but is repeated in all four quadrants. Now the length is $16\sqrt{2}$.

For the final graph, translate this whole shape so that its centre is at $(2,2)$ and again replicate this lattice of four squares in all four quadrants. You now have $16$ of the original squares, and the total length of wire is $64\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Neat answer and probably the shortest way of doing it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get why the square will repeat?

Comment: Comsider the graph of $y=1-x$. Applying a modulus sign to the $x$ means that the parts where $x<0$ are erased, and the rest of the graph is reflected in the $y$ axis. Applying a modulus to the $y$ has the equivalent result, that's why the graph of $|x|+|y|=1$ is the square shape with the original line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$ replicated in all four quadrants. After translation and further applications of modulus signs as before, the same thing happens. And again...